# select combobox item by pressing enter key in c# windows aplication

Tags: c#, winforms

In c#, I want to select combo box items by keyboard and when i press enter after selecting one that item should be selected. how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

try something like this ..., this will explain how to change the items using mouse and key board ,....

I found this method worked fine in all the conditions. But I m not sure if anything more accurate than this method is available.

```
    bool IsMouse = false;

    private void cmbMy_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsMouse)
        {
            //Write the logic if selection is changed by mouse
        }
        else
        {
            //Write the logic if selection is changed by keyboard
        }

        IsMouse = false;
    }

    private void cmbMy_IsMouseCapturedChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsMouse = true;
    }
```

In isMouseCapturedChanged event of combo box i made a bool variable true and when selection changed of the combo box i m checking the bool doing the required task and then setting isMouse to false.

Or you need to bulid your own custom combobox ..

You need build a custom ComboBox class and override [the Control.ProcessKeyEventArgs Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processkeyeventargs.aspx).